# What is the purpose of StreamReader when Stream.Read() exists?

Tags: c#, io, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

This has been bugging me. I know **Stream** is an abstract class and therefore can't be instantiated but it has classes that are derived from it. Why is there a **StreamReader** class and a **Stream.Read()** method (and vice verse for **StreamWriter** and **Stream.Write()**)? You can write to a text file using 3 million different methods and it's rather frustrating trying to get my head around all of these different types and methods in the **System.IO** namespace. I found questions and answers regarding the differences between the writer and reader objects or the derived stream objects themselves but nothing regarding this particular case.

Comment: Since `StreamReader` is abstract, you need an object of a concrete class, such as `TextReader`, to call the `Stream.Read()` method on.  The class and the method are not redundant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`TextReader` (which `StreamReader` is derived from) works with strings. `Stream` works with bytes. The conversion between text and bytes is performed by an `Encoding`.

Choose the right class based on whether the contents of your file text or binary.

It is important to understand the [difference between text and bytes](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: `StreamReader` works with text. It is derived from `TextReader`. A `StreamReader` *wraps* a `Stream` because `Stream` does not support text-based operations. How would you write a string to a file when all you have is a `Stream`?!

Comment: Sorry ignore my last comment, I misread. If a Stream works with bytes why in the heck did Microsoft call it a StreamReader if it works with text? The FCL can be so conflated sometimes.

Comment: They should have called it `StreamTextReader` or `StreamBasedTextReader`. Think of that name as being abbreviated... I understand your confusion because I had the same things to say when I learned this. It totally makes sense when you have some experience with this concept, though.

Comment: Maybe your confusion is more with the design of the BCL and less with the separation of text and bytes.

Comment: BCL? Do you mean FCL? I do indeed understand bytes and that text is just encoded bytes.

Answer (score 2):

A `StreamReader` is a `TextReader` which means it is a `Stream` wrapper. A `TextReader` will convert (or encode) Text data (string or char) to byte[] and write them down to the underlying `Stream`.

Looking at the difference between the two implementations, you can see that `StreamReader` derives from `TextReader`, which, as declared, deals with text instead of bytes. It seems to me as an abstraction for users who want to work with textual representation. Of course, the underlying implementation will need a `Stream` to consume such data, but will provide a level of abstraction for end users.

Answer (score 1):

These two cases are used in different scenario

When you are using the stream class you can access the file for read and write. But when you use streamreader class you can use it to read only. This prevent the usage of file to be written. Sometimes This class is used for security purpose. e.g. for system files which are readonly.