# Cannot change soap message content before deserialize

Tags: c#, soap

I have asp.net web service and a SoapExtension:

```
public class PrefixExtention : SoapExtension
{
    Stream _originalStream;
    Stream _workingStream;

    public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _originalStream = stream;

        _workingStream = new MemoryStream();
        return _workingStream;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return ((PrefixExtentionAttribute)attribute).Filename;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                Copy(_originalStream, _workingStream);
                ChangeStream(_workingStream);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                Copy(_originalStream, _workingStream);
                LogMessageFromStream("1.txt", _workingStream);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("invalid stage");
        }
    }

    void Copy(Stream from, Stream to)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        writer.Flush();
    }

    private void LogMessageFromStream(string filename, Stream stream)
    {
        string soapMessage = string.Empty;

        if (stream.CanRead && stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;

            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);
            soapMessage = rdr.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filename, soapMessage);
    }

    private void ChangeStream(Stream stream)
    {
        Copy(_originalStream, _workingStream);

        string soapMessage = string.Empty;

        if (stream.CanRead && stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;

            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);
            soapMessage = rdr.ReadToEnd();

            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        // do something with message
        soapMessage = soapMessage.Replace("a:", "");
        soapMessage = soapMessage.Replace("xmlns:a=", "xmlns=");

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write(soapMessage);
        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        _workingStream.Position = 0;
        Copy(memoryStream, _workingStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
        _workingStream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

In method ChangeStream() I am trying to change message content - to remove prefixes "a" from xml. I change _workingStream by Copy(memoryStream, _workingStream); but then SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize is not being called. How can I modify soap message so that my object (in web method) will be deserialized correctly with modified message?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're working with bytes and not strings, so you'll first have to convert the `Stream` that's being passed to `ChangeStream` to a string.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648501/2344773) for more info.

**EDIT:** The above is wrong. It appears you're already reading the stream and encoding it. However, it also looks like you're trying to replace characters in a string object that could be null if tge stream is null. Are you certain youre getting data back from your service call?